# How to display user city and state, and profile picture in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am making a custom profile page for the users on my WordPress site. I have been able to easily display the username of the logged in user. But I am running into a couple issues:

1) I am having a really hard time finding out how to display the logged in user's city and state. This information is stored in Dashboard/Users/'username' under the shipping address section.

2) I cannot figure out how to display the user's profile picture. From what I have read, user profile pictures are stored on Gravatar's servers...

I am displaying this on a left-sidebar...Here is my code so far for displaying the username

**sidebar-profile.php**

```
<div id="sidebar-profile" class="sidebar">
    <div>
        <h4>
            <?php 
                $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
                echo $current_user->user_login;
            ?>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'profile' ); ?>
</div>
```

I have tried a few different things and all have failed to work.

Also, I am a novice web developer so there may be some errors with my approach to displaying these values.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to grab the users gravatar image with your above code like so:

```
<div id="sidebar-profile" class="sidebar">
<div>
    <h4>
        <?php 
            $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
            echo $current_user->user_login;
            echo get_avatar( $current_user->user_email, 32 );
        ?>
    </h4>
</div>
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'profile' ); ?>
</div>
```

This will display a `<img>` tag with the gravatar, there is also additional arguments you can use with the `get_avatar()` function to allow you to customize the output further: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar

I'm assuming for the city and state of the user you are using WooCommerce, if so then you should be able to grab this information from the users post meta:

```
$shippingCity  = get_post_meta($current_user->ID, 'shipping_city', true);
$shippingState = get_post_meta($current_user->ID, 'shipping_state', true);
```

Comment: Thank you! 'echo get_avatar( $current_user->user_email, 32 );' worked. However, I was not able to get the city and state to display with the given code. But I think that is due to another issue I have to look into.